# How To Run Robot Framework Project Developed In Eclipse Via Command Line

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I have created a project using Robot Framework in Eclipse via RED. I want to know how can I run this project via Windows Command Line, so that I can create a Jenkins job to run it at a particular time ? I have tried using the steps for running Eclipse Project from command line via Debug mode, but it is not helping.

Please find the project structure below

[image]

I also tried to reach this location and run this test suit using the command

`Robot Test_Suite.robot`, but then I'm getting below 2 errors

1.) `Importing test library 'Excel_Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Excel_Library`. This file is a python file which I have written to support Excel operations and it is present at below location in the project -

[image]

2.) `No Such File Or Directory - Path_To_External_Input\\External_Inputs.xls`

This file contains the input which is being read before performing operations related to test suite and it is present at below location -

[image]

Do I need to add those in the command line if so how to take care of that ? This project run smoothly from eclipse but only problem is coming from command line.

Comment: The answer depends quite a lot depending on e.g., your Robot file/folder structure, etc.. You can also take a look at the official [RF User Guide - Executing test cases](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-test-cases). Also, please take a look how to provide a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you can launch it in Eclipse as a Java application, there is a _Show Command Line_ button in the Launch Configuration dialog for that. Otherwise, give a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @asprtrmp, As per your valuable suggestion, I have added the details. Let me know if further information needs to be added.

Comment: @howlger, I have done the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are able to run robot correctly, although I would prefer lowercase R with `robot` command.

1) I think you have misspelled the library name. If it's a pip package, try `ExcelLibrary` instead, and check that you have installed it by `pip list` command or equivalent.

2) Please check the path. Without additional info on how and where the file is called and where the file is located are needed.

Comment: further details have been added. Also Excel Library is a python file which I have written to perform some operations related to Excel.